# What's the difference between 'constant of integration' and 'undetermined coeffcient'?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm teaching myself Calculus. On page 573 of Thomas Calculus, it's said "Hence we have ... where K is the arbitrary constant of integration(to avoid confusion with the undetermined coefficient we labeled as C)." as the picture below shows.

This avoiding-confusion statement really confused me. Always, I never thought about the part attached at the end of indefinite integration. And, also it seems the author choose the letter C and K randomly in the Section 8.3 of this book.

So, can anyone tell me what's the difference between those two?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

[8.3 Integration of Rational Functions by Partial Fractions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL9zb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setting up a "decomposition template" for decomposing a rational function into partial fractions, it's conventional to go through as much of the alphabet as necessary for the "unknowns" in the numerators: those are the "undetermined coefficients" (although, I guess, once you figure out what they have to be, I guess they're "finally determined" coefficients) For example, writing

$$\dfrac{2x^2 + 5x - 1}{(x - 1)^2(x^2 + 3)} = \dfrac{A}{x - 1} + \dfrac{B}{(x - 1)^2} + \dfrac{Cx + D}{x^2 + 3},$$

the $A, B, C$, and $D$ are the "undetermined coefficients."

It would be bad form to use $C$ to mean both "the coefficient of $x$ in the numerator of $\frac{Cx + D}{x^2 + 3}$" *and* "the constant of integration in $F(x) + C$"; those are two totally different things. So, whenever "$C$" (or anything, really) has already been used to name something, it's a good idea to *not* reuse the name for a different thing, at least within a single problem.

Hence the author choosing between ${}+C$ and ${}+K$ for constants of integration. I'll bet that if you look, the ${}+K$ is used *only* if the decomposition template already used $C$.

Comment: pjs36, thank you for your detailed answer. It really eased me. I should read the book more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

"Undetermined coefficient" just means a coefficient that we don't know yet, as usual in algebra.  The constant of integration $C$ is an unknown that arises in a certain context - it is the unknown constant that is necessary because there are multiple possible antiderivatives for any given function $f(x)$. It is usually denoted $C$, but in this particular case the symbol $C$ was already used with a different meaning, so the author chose to use $K$ instead.

Comment: Jair, thank you for taking me out of the dead end! I totally got it.

Answer (score 2):

$C$ and $K$ are just tokens.   The symbols have no fixed meaning until we assign them one.   So while $C$ is commonly used as an arbitrary constant from integration, if it is already used elsewhere then we need to assign a free symbol to that purpose.   $K$ is often a good standby, but we don't have to use either.

$$\int (Ux+V)\operatorname d x = \tfrac 12 Ux^2+Vx + T \qquad\text{where }{T\text{ is an arbitrary constant of integration}\\U,V\text{ are our unknown coefficients}}$$

Comment: Graham, thank you! I got it.